# OAuth2 idToken is verified, but Login Required error persists

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-api-nodejs-client

So cutting right to the chase...
I'm integrating an Angular front-end with an express back-end.

The login happens using angularx-social-login in the front-end(trying to avoid redirects) and the idToken is sent to the back-end for verification. The scopes are added during the login at the front-end.

After using google-auth-library to verify the token everything is good and correct.

But once a service.people.connections.list() for getting google contacts is called a Login Required error persist. I've tried using the access token I get at the front-end, the payload I get from the verification and all that... I'm sure I'm missing a single step, but I have no clue.
req.headers.authorization here is the idToken.

```
const client = new OAuth2Client(CLIENT_ID);
    async function verify() {
        const ticket = await client.verifyIdToken({
            idToken: req.headers.authorization,
            audience: CLIENT_ID
            
        });
        
        const payload = ticket.getPayload();
        console.log(payload);
        const userid = payload['sub'];

        const service = google.people({ version: 'v1' });
        service.people.connections.list({
            resourceName: 'people/me',
            pageSize: 10,
            personFields: 'names,emailAddresses',
        }, (err, res) => {
            if (err) return console.error('The API returned an error: ' + err);
            const connections = res.data.connections;
            if (connections) {
                console.log('Connections:');
                connections.forEach((person) => {
                    if (person.names && person.names.length > 0) {
                        console.log(person.names[0].displayName);
                    } else {
                        console.log('No display name found for connection.');
                    }
                });
            } else {
                console.log('No connections found.');
            }
        });
    };
```

Comment: Im not sure i understand the problem your code will always need to be authorized unless you are storing a refresh token for use next time.

Comment: Yes, that is true. This integration is a one time thing, so there is no need to store the refresh token. I'll be storing those once more functionality for the Google API is needed.